# resize font-size of direct child which has class fs-5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, media-queries, bootstrap-5

I am using a media query where I indicate that based on the pixels I want all direct children (hence the p's) of the div to have a specific font-size. Among these there is a p which has class=fs-5.

I saw the responsive, the p that has that qulla class is not modified, it remains as it is.

How can I change it?

```css
.foots {
  background-color: #0000e4;
  top: -40px;
  right: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .foots>p {
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row position-relative">

  <div class="col-3 position-absolute foots text-white text-center p-3">
    <p class="fs-5">Other Lorem Stuff</p>
    <p> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p> > Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    <p> > Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus malesuada auctor.</p>
    <p> > Vestibulum pellentesque</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: "I saw the responsive, the p that has that qulla class is not modified, it remains as it is." Are you referring to the `p` with the `fs-5` class not being changed from the media query? It seems to be changed by the media-query in the snippet, did you include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your head?

Comment: @カメロン yes in the media query it remains as it is. How can I change it?

Comment: In the snippet, all `p` elements are being affected by the media query at the specified 950 px width. Do you not want the first p element to be affected?

Comment: @カメロン no I also want to resize the p with class f-5. Only this is not resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to specify `!important` to your font-size style. All Bootstrap classes use `!important` by default, which will take priority over any non-important specified classes, including media queries.

```css
.foots {
  background-color: #0000e4;
  top: 0px;
  right: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .foots>p {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row position-relative">
  <div class="col-3 position-absolute foots text-white text-center p-3">
    <p class="fs-5">Other Lorem Stuff</p>
    <p> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p> > Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    <p> > Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus malesuada auctor.</p>
    <p> > Vestibulum pellentesque</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Response to comment ~

You can select all `p` elements except the first child using the following CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .foots>p:not(:first-child) {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

See it working here:

```css
.foots {
  background-color: #0000e4;
  top: 0px;
  right: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .foots>p:not(:first-child) {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .foots>p:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row position-relative">
  <div class="col-3 position-absolute foots text-white text-center p-3">
    <p class="fs-5">Other Lorem Stuff</p>
    <p> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p> > Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    <p> > Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus malesuada auctor.</p>
    <p> > Vestibulum pellentesque</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: if I wanted that p with font size equal to 15px, leaving the other p 10px how could I do?

Comment: therefore the p which has class fs-5 of 15 px and the other p of 10px

Comment: @a_l_e_x See edits.

Comment: nothing has changed, the p returns to me as it is

Comment: @a_l_e_x Lol, do I really need to add another snippet to show you?

Comment: yes to understand how to proceed. You will be reciprocated

Comment: @a_l_e_x "if I wanted that p with font size equal to 15px, leaving the other p 10px how could I do?" See the second snippet. The code does exactly that.

Comment: the second snippet leaves me the p with class fs-5 but it is too big in the media query. So I want it to be 15px in the media query. I hope I have been clearer

Comment: @a_l_e_x Okay, I think I understand you now. See edits on snippet #2.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the `class="fs-5"` and instead specify it like this to make all `p` fonts the same size across the site.

```
p{
  font-size: --px;
}
```

Then, in the rest of your CSS if you need it to be larger or smaller than that for certain elements you can specify as a percentage of that initial font size. For example, you might want your copyright statement to be slightly smaller at the foot of each page (or your `.foots` text).

```
.foots{
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

To be honest, it looks like you are trying to use `fs-5` to make the first paragraph slightly bigger than the rest. Like a lead-in to the page. So Bootstrap does this automtically if you use `class="lead"`. Here are the docs...  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/#lead